# Replacing strings using grunt-replace

Tags: javascript, regex, configuration, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I would like to replace `url("images/` string to some other string e.g. `ZZZZZZZZZZZZ` using grunt-replace.

I use following configuration:

```
replace: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            patterns: [
                {
                    match: /"/g,
                    replacement: 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
                }
            ]
        },
        files: [
            {
             expand: true, flatten: true, 
             src: ['dist/app/css/app.css'], dest: 'dist/app/css2/'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I've tried `match: /"/g` and `/images/g` and both of them were replaced, but none of those worked:

- `match : /"images/g`
- `match : /\"images/g`
- `match : /("images)/g` //worked when tested on http://regex101.com/r/tU5iM3/2
- `match : /(\"images)/g` //worked when tested on http://regex101.com/r/tU5iM3/3

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**
I've added `files` section of my grunt-replace configuration + working `/images/g` example.
I'm using some other Grunt tasks and Grunt replace is last one:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['useminPrepare', 'copy', 'concat', 'uglify', 'cssmin', 'usemin', 'replace']);
```

But I don't see how it it could break my regex replace. I'm testing my configuration by running command:
`grunt -v --stack && grep -R "ZZZZZZZZZZZZ" .`

Comment: All the `regexp` matches correctly your goal (in the `http://regex101.com` each expression generates 2 matches, the difference is the last two also generate matched group due to `()` ). Besides looking on the `grunt-replace` documentation:  https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace your `patterns` definition is totally correct, maybe the error is in another place.

Comment: I've updated my question with some more data. I just can't figure out where this error might be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your regex101 links point to code using the Python regex library, rather than JavaScript, which is what Grunt uses.  Next, the `(` and `\` characters need to be escaped, but none of the others do.  The regexp you're looking for is:

```
/url\("images\//g
```

(see https://regex101.com/r/aY9hY0/1 to play with it)